# Which app markets should I deploy my Android game to?

Tags: android, appstore

I just launched my Android game today. I'm curious to know where I can deploy it. Of course, Google Play is the veritable king of markets, and my own game site will be next.

After that, which marketplaces are mature and are worth deploying to?

I looked at:

- [SlideMe](http://slideme.org)
- [GetJar](http://getjar.com)
- [Soc.io](http://mall.soc.io)

And some other ones that I didn't use:

- YAAM (kept crashing and erroring out)
- 1Mobile (couldn't figure out how to upload my app)
- Insyde Market

My question is really, which ones are out there and are worth uploading too? (And 1Mobile seems good, but just can't figure out how to upload.)

Each site requires their own size screenshots and logo, so it's a bunch of extra work. I'd rather stick to the 80/20 rule and apply 20% effort to hit 80% of the markets.

Answer (score 2):

The [Amazon Appstore for Android](https://developer.amazon.com/welcome.html) would be my first thought after Google Play. I guess that I don't see the harm in adding your game to every app store that will accept it. Is the extra work of making some more screenshots that bad?

I can't imagine that the different markets require such a big difference that you couldn't take some screenshots at high res, and then write a script to resize them for each market you want to update?

Comment: The amazon app store is definitely the other major one to consider.  Especially considering that the Kindle Fire is (by all accounts I've heard of) the top selling Android tablet out there.  http://gigaom.com/2012/02/21/amazon-appstore-more-lucrative-for-many-devs-than-android-market/

Comment: Actually, Amazon seems to be the one app store that you need to consider very carefully. They have got some pretty ridiculous terms, like reserving the right to set the price pretty much however they want, and they DO use it. See also: http://igdaboard.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/important-advisory-about-amazon%E2%80%99s-appstore-distribution-terms-2/ and http://blog.shiftyjelly.com/2011/08/02/amazon-app-store-rotten-to-the-core/ and http://bithack.se/news/apparatus-amazon-july-4-2011.html

Comment: They also charge $99/month. I've used exclusively free app stores so far.

Comment: Its not $99 a month, it's $99 per year.

Comment: My bad, that's what I meant. Brain fart. It is per year.

Comment: @ashes999 Then it looks like you've covered the bases correctly. As for Amazon... while those stories are sad, and maybe the Amazon store has some kinks (ignoring the manifest file to filter incompatible devices is pretty bad) I think that the more exposure you can get the better. I have a WP7 app, and I am trying a similar approach to the one listed here: http://www.wpcentral.com/effects-making-app-free-and-numbers-go-it It may be an apples to oranges comparison, but I think its at least reading that point of view on a limited time free app. (which seems to be the biggest issue with Amazon)